# Filter based on all columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with several columns and each column can have a value of 0 OR 1 ..I just want to eliminate the rows where all the columns have 0 .. I just want to consider the rows if at least one column have a value of 1

Comment: Which dbms do you use?

Comment: This seems simple... have you tried to do anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM A_TABLE_YOU_DID_NOT_NAME
WHERE col1 + col2 + ... + colN >= 1
```

Will not return all 0 and at least one of them will be 1.

Comment: There is one possible drawback. If one column contain `NULL` entire condition will be `UNKNOWN`. You should also add `FROM` clause

Comment: @lad2025 -- NULL is not included when a there is the statement "each column can have a value of 0 OR 1".  Good point about the FROM clause, I added that in.

Answer (score -1):

IN SQL Server, you can make use of OR:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE [column1] = 1 OR [column2] = 1...
```